# Installation never completes in AppCenter

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, appcenter

Recently, I am using Elementary OS and i like it. I am a Mac user but i also use Windows for gaming, so UI + functionality wise it is perfect for me. I found one issue, i was trying to install `Steam`, after the progress bar went little bit more than 50%, it was stuck for more than 5 minutes. So, i forced quit `AppCenter` and when i went to application menu, i saw `Steam` is there already. Same thing happened with system update, it was stuck for almost 20 minutes after 60%. Is this a bug or something is wrong from my side?

Comment: This hasn't ever occur on my PC. What happens when you perform system upgrade via Terminal: `sudo apt upgrade` ? Are there any error messages or warnings? Does the upgrade process go error-free or does it also gets stuck, just like when using AppCenter?

Comment: hey @a-tokarev, i did not see any error message, although it took around 20 minutes to finish `upgrade`. I believe the time is normal right?

Comment: 20 minutes for a regular system upgrade? Unbelievably long, if you ask me. How fast is your internet connection? (you can measure it here, for instance: https://www.speedtest.net) Mine is 50 MBps and regular system updates or app installations usually take less than a minute.

Comment: try reinstalling steam from the command line: `sudo apt install --reinstall steam`

Comment: @Maccer just tried but still same, after i click steam from Applications, it just pops up in dock panel, stays there for few seconds and then disappears, same as before. :(

Comment: Open steam from Terminal and check the output. It should show you why it closes. If you need help, create a pastebin.com with your terminal output and I'll help you find the issue.

Comment: @Maccer maybe a stupid question, how to run Steam from terminal?

Comment: Open Terminal and type `steam`. You can open it with Win+T . Then copy all the output until the program crashes.

Comment: @Maccer hey, thank you for your message. So, I was able to fix the problem. I did exactly what you told me to do, ran `Steam` on the terminal and found out that it is complaining about a missing directory. So, I created that missing directory and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much. :)